# Validation rule on lead conversion. preventing specific users ownership of records

Tags: validation-rule, lead-conversion

I'm trying to prevent a specific user from owning Opportunity/account/contact records upon reassignment on lead conversion.

Here is what i got so far and I cant seem to get it to work... Any kind of assistance would be awesome.

```
AND( 
IsConverted = TRUE, 
OwnerId='0054J000001Abb2')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable a setting for validation rule to work: Documentation [validation rule not firing when converting Leads](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331020&type=1&mode=1) says-

> To enforce a Validation Rule when converting leads, you need to enable
>   'Require validation for Converted Leads.'
>
> Note: If the 'Require validation for Converted Leads' setting is not
>   available, please contact Salesforce Support to enable the 'Use Apex
>   Lead Convert' permission.

Comment: Just verified that this is already ticket...

Comment: @AndrewSeanBaldwin I assume you have validation rule on Lead, because I tried creating a lead validation with your formula and it works.